# running selenium webdriver test in firefox is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to click on a submenu item on a when page. I used following code to perform the action.

```
    WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='main-menu']"))

    WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='sub-menu-item2']"))

    mainMenu.click();
    actions.moveToElement(mainMenu).build().perform();
    subMenu.click();
```

This code works fine while using Chrome browser, whereas it is not working with Firefox.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @derloopkat according to my test once I click on the submenu item I have to validate an element is present in the page that is loaded. Since it is not able to click on the submenu item the test is not able to find the element that I am trying to validate. I sort of stuck in earlier step of my test

Comment: In your code increase timeout and maximize the window size before clicking submenu. Perhaps default window size is different in FF, forcing a different layout where the element is not visible. These are the two most common issues causing element not found in Selenium. If problem persist please add your html or a link.

Comment: @derloopkat I am getting following error while trying to click on the submenu item "Could not find webelement key"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading a couple of posts I came to know geckodriver has not yet implement Actions "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233" this proves my code won't work when running my test is firefox.

Instead of using Actions I used JavaScriptExecutor and it worked perfectly fine for me here is the command that I used.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", mainMenu);
subMenu.click();
```

This works perfectly fine on both Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept this as the answer when you can so the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffC sure will do